# Phonegap 3.1 takes forever to load on iOS 7

Tags: ios, cordova

I am building an Phonegap 3.1 app on ios 7.0.3, it works fine on previous versions, but not it takes like at least 1 minute to load the app, any suggestions.

Comment: Any information about what code or elements should appear in the app home page? I have Cordova 3.1 running on iOS 7 and the load times are not that bad even when I have images in my home page.

Comment: It seem it takes for ever between after index.html is loaded message to actually I get to my own code after mobileinit.